# How to use hint in mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
Event.find({
    "programManagerId": req.userId,
    "status": "ongoing"
}, {
    'trainingId': 1,
    'programId': 1,
    'startDate': 1,
    'endDate': 1,
    'status': 1,
    'module': 1,
    'eventName': 1,
}).populate({
    path: "programId",
    select: 'programName'
}).populate({
    path: "trainingId",
    select: 'trainingName detail mode'
}).hint({programManagerId: 1, status: 1}).exec(function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        res.status(500).json(err);
    } else if (!data) {
        res.status(404).json({
            "info": "data not found"
        })
    } else {
        console.log(data);
        res.status(200).json(data);
    }
})
```

I'm trying to use `hint` cursor for indexing the `programManagerId` and `status` but while running the code I'm getting `500 error`.

When I've run the code without using `hint` the code is working fine.

Is there any possible ways to use `hint`.

Comment: Can we have the whole error stack please? Did you have created the index?

Comment: GET /api/programManagerOngoingEvents 500 1160.682 ms - 821
This is what I'm getting as error.

Comment: hint() is here to force mongodb to use an index with your query, but this index has to be created before.

Comment: GET /api/programManagerOngoingEvents `500`  1160.682 ms - 821
This is what I'm getting as error.
No I didn't created any index because If I'm not wrong then `hint` helps us to create new indexes or I'm wrong because still have this confusion.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any method to do it without creating indexes.